# how to pass data to modal dialog in laravel (Update method usinf modal box)?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I want to create a new post in my Database using modal box,  and all works fine but when I use the button edit to update the post using modal dialog doenst work, I just want to take the cod('id') via a button from my view and pass to the modal.

the button code:

```
  <a class="tip" id="test"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myAlert2" title="Modifier">
```

and this is my code modal dialog

```
 <div id="myAlert2" class="modal hide" id="modal-edit">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                <h3>Modifier un espace de travail</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>

                <div class="form--field">
                    <label class="labgroupe">Sujet *</label>

                    <input type="text" name="sujet" id="sujet" value="" class="form--element"  placeholder="Sujet..." >
                </div>
                <div class="form--field">
                    <label class="labgroupe">Objectif du groupe</label>
                    <input type="text" name="objectif" class="form--element"   placeholder="Objectif..." >
                </div>

                <div class="form--field" >
                    <label class="labgroupe">Plan d'action:</label>
                    <textarea  class="form--element textarea" name="textarea" placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
                </div>
              @endforeach
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Validate" id="button2" class="btn btn-success">
                <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" href="#">Cancel</a> </div>
        </div>
```

Any help plz ?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use 2 id's on the same div

```
<div id="myAlert2" class="modal hide" id="modal-edit">
```

changed to

```
<div id="myAlert2" class="modal hide">
```

and use same id on data-target="#myAlert2"

Comment: when i pass id in data-target="#myAlert2" like that data-target="#myAlert2-{{ post->id }}" doesnt work  
the modal dialog myalert doen't open

Comment: the same id of what ?

Answer (score 0):

Modal button:

```
<a href="#" class="tip" id="test" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myAlert2" title="Modifier" data-id="{!!$id_or_codid!!}"></a>
```

On your script, add this:

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Then add an input in the modal called #id.

```
<input type="text" id="id">
```